# Angular ng-repeat controlling?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to repeat specific element only a certain number of times, rather than having all of the elements repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat='el in elements'>
    <div>{{el.someValue}}</div>//repeat here only 3 times 
    <div>{{el.someValue}}</div>// repeat here only 2times something like this
</div>
```

Can I do something like this?

Comment: Not with that syntax. If you removed the last div. It will work. Why do you need 2 different divs in there like that? When the repeater works it will leave each element in a div giving you the same amount of divs.

Comment: @floor what if I want to repeat only 3 times but there lot's of elements? I do not want to load everything...

Comment: you may use custom filter service for ng-repeat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can limit the number of items displayed using `limitTo`

```
<!-- Only display the first 5 elements -->
<div ng-repeat='el in elements | limitTo: 5'>
  <div>{{el.someValue}}</div>
</div>
```

Or if you want more control over what to display and what not, you can use a filter:

```
<div ng-repeat='el in elements | filter: myFilter'>
  <div>{{el.someValue}}</div>
</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.myFilter = function(element) {
  // return true if element is displayed of false otherwise
}
```

Comment: @Shaxrillo but if it is inside what are you repeating? Is `el.someValue` an array itself?

Comment: Can you add what exactly is in `elements` in your question? It is still unclear for me

Comment: So you want to be able to do something like 

```
<div ng-repeat="el in elements">
    <div ng-repeat="val in someValues | limitTo: 3"></div>
</div>
```

?